# Classifying true positives, false positives and false negatives using 2 sets of coordinates

Tags: algorithm, matlab, coordinates

Let's say I have two sets of coordinates. Set A is the ground truth coordinates and set B is the newly generated coordinates.

I am classifying the following way:

1. True positives if the coordinate in set A is at least within 5 pixels of a coordinate in B.
2. False negative for all the coordinates in set A that do not find matches with any coordinates in set B.
3. False positive for all the coordinates in set B that do find matches with any coordinates in set A.

The sets do not correspond. By that I mean, the first coordinate in set A doesn't have any relevance with the first coordinate in set B.

Here is my code:

```
clear;
w = warning ('off','all');
coordA = dir('./GT*.txt');
coordB = dir('./O*.txt');

for i =1:length(coordA)
    TP = [];
    FP = [];
    FN = [];
    %read coordinate files
    fir = fopen(coordA(i).name, 'r');
    disp(coordA(i).name);
    A = textscan(fir, '%d %d\n');
    fclose(fir);

    disp(coordB(i).name);
    sec = fopen(coordB(i).name, 'r');
    B = textscan(fir, '%d, %d\n');
    fclose(sec);

    A_x = A{1};
    A_y = A{2};
    B_x = B{1};
    B_y = B{2};
    for j = 1:length(A_x)
        flag = 1;  %this flag indicates false negatives
        for k = 1:length(B_x)
            X = [A_x(j), A_y(j); B_x(k), B_y(k)];
            d = pdist(X);
            if(d <= 5)
                flag = 0; %Ax and Ay 
                %the problem is here---------
                TP = [TP [B_x(k) B_y(k)]];
                B_x(k) = 0;
                B_y(k) = 0;
            end  
        end
        if(flag)
            FN = [FN [A_x(j) A_y(j)]];
        end
    end
    for b = find(B_x)
        FP = [FP [B_x(b) B_y(b)]];
    end
end
```

The problem(please note the comments in the code and example below) I am facing is the following. Let's say there are two coordinates in set A that are really close to each other. When I go to check for TPs in set B and I find a coordinate that's within 5 pixels, I mark it as true positive then remove that coordinate from set B. However, let's say I'm trying to check for the other nearby coordinate from set A. Well, it will be marked as a false negative since I removed a close by coordinate in set B when checking for a different coordinate.

I thought of not removing coordinates in set B even when I find a true positive, but then how would I find false positives?

I did this in Matlab, but any language is fine with me.

Example coordinates:
A:

```
250 500
251 500
```

B:

```
250 501
```

The second coordinate should also be considered as true positive, but its being considered as false negative.

Comment: I would suggest that you set a parameter for the radius `r (=5 in your case)` within which you check for proximity and then you could run a search to identify points in set `A` which are within radius `2*r` (and possibly store them in a set `C`?). In this way, whenever you find a point in A that meets your criteria, you can immediately check the other points that are close. However, removing entries from set `B` is not always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By altering your code, I believe the following part should do what you are looking for. Basically, instead of removing entries, you can just use logical indexing:

```
clear;
w = warning ('off','all');
coordA = dir('./GT*.txt');
coordB = dir('./O*.txt');

radius = 5;

for i =1:length(coordA)

    % read coordinate files
    fir = fopen(coordA(i).name, 'r');
    disp(coordA(i).name);
    A = textscan(fir, '%d %d\n');
    fclose(fir);

    disp(coordB(i).name);
    sec = fopen(coordB(i).name, 'r');
    B = textscan(fir, '%d, %d\n');
    fclose(sec);

    A_x = A{1};
    A_y = A{2};
    B_x = B{1};
    B_y = B{2};

    % Initialize logical arrays to reflect the 
    % Status of each entry
    TP = zeros(length(A_x),1); % no entry of A is considered true positive
    FN = ones(length(A_x),1);  % all entries of A are considered false negative
    FP = ones(length(B_x),1);  % all entries of B are considered false positive

    for ij = 1:length(A_x)
        for ijk = 1:length(B_x)
            X = [A_x(ij), A_y(ij); B_x(ijk), B_y(ijk)];
            d = pdist(X)
            if (d <= radius)
                TP(ij) = 1; % just found a true positive
                FP(ijk) = 0;% no more a false positive
            end
        end 
    end

    % Obtain the lists containing the appropriate values
    % For true positive, just use logical indexing and TP array
    True_Pos = [A_x(logical(TP))', A_y(logical(TP))'];
    % For false negative, remove TP from FN
    False_Neg = [A_x(logical(FN-TP))', A_y(logical(FN-TP))']; 
    % For false positive, whatever remained switched on in FP
    False_Pos = [B_x(logical(FP))', B_y(logical(FP))'];
end
```

There are other approaches if you do need to remove entries (see my comment above). Moreover, there is a more clean way to code it but I tried to be explicit and follow your implementation.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, if the end array is of the form `1x4` that means the first coordinate's `x` value is the first element and the `y` element is the third element, correct?

Comment: I tried to make the size of the end arrays `jx2`, where column 1 holds `x` values and column 2 holds the `y`s. `j` would be the number of entries that conform with your criteria. So for `True_pos` and `False_Neg` the following relation must be true: `size(A_x) == size(True_Pos,1) + size(False_Neg,1)`.